# How to run a proccess completely seperate in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a Java program which starts another process with `ProcessBuilder` like the following:

```
String commands[] = {"ruby", "/home/scripts/script.rb"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
Map<String,String> map = builder.environment();
map.put("TYPE", "sometype");
try {
    builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Some time after the process starts executing (a small Ruby Script which should not terminate) the Java program exits.

The problem is, once the Java program finishes executing, all sub-processes are closed, also the Ruby Script.

I found some similar questions but the answer was always, the Process is independent. But it is not like that in my case, the Ruby code will always stop executing if the Java program exits.

I tried the Java code on a Debian Jessie System with Java 8u66

Comment: Start the process with `nohup`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is `nohup` something like `screen`? Would the nohup process terminate after Ruby finishes executing?

Comment: There might be some environment specific setting.  
For example, if I need to run 'cmd.exe' in windows, I need to provide:  
`String commands[] = {"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe","/c","start","C:/users/amber/desktop/temp.bat"};`
  
  This is temp.bat  
`Set COUNTER=0
echo off

:loop
if %COUNTER%==3 set COUNTER=0
if %COUNTER%==2 set COUNTER=3
if %COUNTER%==1 set COUNTER=2
if %COUNTER%==0 set COUNTER=1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
echo %COUNTER%
goto loop`

Comment: @Amber OP specified debian linux. [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard command which (in a shell or subprocess) is used to ignore the HUP (or HangUp) signal.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok thank you that solved my problem. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, once the Java program finishes executing, all sub-processes are closed, also the Ruby Script.

On *nix systems ([POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) really, including Debian Linux) the process is sent a [`HUP` signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (`SIGHUP` or *hangup*) when its' parent process ends. You can use the [`nohup(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) command when you start a subprocess to *ignore* the *hangup* from the *child* process.

**Alternatively**, you could *potentially* make use of the Ruby [`Signal` Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Signal.html) and use `Signal.trap(HUP)` to handle it some other way.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Process.getOutputStream, wait for output from the process with runs Ruby, and if it takes too much time, then you can run in the background also.

Comment: I don't want to wait for the Ruby Script to finish executing before exiting from Java. How can you start a process in the background from Java?

Comment: you can add nohup or & in your command array to take the process in background in java.

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("nohup ruby /home/scripts/script.rb &");